# Configure the "prod" and "dev" of an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I try to set up the "dev" and "prod" environments for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application, but it does not work... Here is my config:

The `appsettings.json` content (exactly the same as `appsettings.Development.json`)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": { "Default": "Warning" }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyAppContext":     
      "...AccountName=MyApptables4dev; AccountKey=xxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "AzureAd": {
      "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
      "ClientId": "xxxxxxx",
      "Domain": "MyAppapp-dev.azurewebsites.net",
      "TenantId": "yyyyyyy"
    }
  }
}
```

for the **`appsettings.Production.json`** just the connection string and the domain name changes:

```
"MyAppContext":"...AccountName=MyApptables4dev;AccountKey=yyyyyy==;EndpointSuffix=core..."
```

and

```
"Domain": "MyAppapp.azurewebsites.net",
```

The `Startup.cs`:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder = builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();

    // Register the IConfiguration instance which "ConnectionStrings" binds against.
    //services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
    services.Configure<AppSecrets>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<ITableRepositories, TableClientOperationsService>();
    // ...
```

the `secrets.json` (located in the Users folder) content

```
{
  "MyAppTablesConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myapptables4dev;AccountKey=xxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

And finally the Class to access the DB (AzureTables in my case)

```
public class TableClientOperationsService : ITableRepositories
{
    // ... 

    public TableClientOperationsService() { }
    public TableClientOperationsService(IOptions<AppSecrets> optionsAccessor)
    {
        tables = new Dictionary<string, CloudTable>();            
        // 'null' in 'prod'!
        connectionString = optionsAccessor.Value.MyAppTablesConnectionString; 
    }
```

Knowing that `MyAppTablesConnectionString` is "null" in "Production", maybe the problem comes from there, but I don't know how to make it work with both the `MyAppContext` and the `MyAppTablesConnectionString` connection strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code read value from `MyAppTablesConnectionString` setting:

```
connectionString = optionsAccessor.Value.MyAppTablesConnectionString;
```

But accordingly to provided info, only dev env has this setting (defined via secret.json and read by `builder = builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();`).

So yes, production environment got `null`, as the setting isn't defined in any configuration sources:

- user secret isn't used with prod
- `appsettings` files don't describe `MyAppTablesConnectionString`
- and you don't pass this value via env variables.

Comment: Do an have an idea of ways to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Serge just select appropriate configuration sources and define the setting. As you already using env variables as one of sources (`builder.AddEnvironmentVariables()`) and conn string is a sensitive information,  it may be a good option for you -> add an env variable with the same name as your setting and set conn string as it's value. If you deploy to Azure, think about using their Key-Value storage. In general, you may even put it into another encrypted configuration file. Look into [Data Protection API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection) for more info.

Comment: my problem was that the corresponding Environment Variables already existed on the server, but instead of updating it on azure, I tried to update them in the `appsetings.json` `dev` and `prod`, that has any effect on deployed and running in Azure application :") so once I modified it in azure corresponding slots app setting it worked like a charm.